# How do I get and install up to date versions of JupyterLab extensions?

Tags: pip, jupyter-lab

All of my JupyterLab extensions are reported as out of date, but I can't figure out how to bring them up to date.

When I run `jupyter labextension list`, I get:

```
[automata] ~/Documents/Projects/Coding/Python/automata (master *=) $ jupyter labextension list
JupyterLab v4.0.1
/Users/Rax/Documents/Projects/Coding/Python/venvs/automata/share/jupyter/labextensions
        jupyterlab_pygments v0.2.2 enabled  X (python, jupyterlab_pygments)
        nbdime-jupyterlab v2.2.0 enabled  X
        jupyter-matplotlib v0.11.3 enabled OK
        @jupyterlab/git v0.41.0 enabled  X (python, jupyterlab-git)
        @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager v5.0.7 enabled  X (python, jupyterlab_widgets)


   The following extensions are outdated:
        jupyterlab_pygments
        nbdime-jupyterlab
        @jupyterlab/git
        @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager
        
   Consider running "jupyter labextension update --all" to check for updates.
```

But running `jupyter labextension update --all` gives

```
(Deprecated) Updating extensions with the jupyter labextension update command is now deprecated and will be removed in a future major version of JupyterLab.

Users should manage prebuilt extensions with package managers like pip and conda, and extension authors are encouraged to distribute their extensions as prebuilt packages
```

and has no effect.

How do I get and install up to date versions of JupyterLab extensions?

---

Running `jupyter --paths` gives:

```
config:
    /Users/Rax/.jupyter
    /Users/Rax/Library/Python/3.11/etc/jupyter
    /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/etc/jupyter
    /usr/local/etc/jupyter
    /etc/jupyter
data:
    /Users/Rax/Library/Jupyter
    /Users/Rax/Library/Python/3.11/share/jupyter
    /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/share/jupyter
    /usr/local/share/jupyter
    /usr/share/jupyter
runtime:
    /Users/Rax/Library/Jupyter/runtime
```

Comment: This might be a bit misleading - e.g. `@jupyterlab/git` is not outdated, at least not the version from `jupyterlab-git`; maybe you have multiple versions installed? Try: 1) Uninstall any extensions which were installed using `jupyter labextension` using `jupyter labextension uninstall extension_name`  2) update the extensions using `pip install -U extension_name`

Comment: @krassowski Yeah I did that for every extension "JupyterLab cannot uninstall <extension> since it was installed outside of JupyterLab. Use the same method used to install this extension to uninstall this extension."

Comment: @krassowski I think they're all installed using `pip` (as they should be)

Comment: @krassowski Also tried a complete deletion and rebuild of the venv from scratch and ended up at the same place.

Comment: You still may have another older copy of the extension in another place, outside of your venv. Use `jupyter --paths`

Comment: @krassowski I'm not sure how to interpret the output of `jupyter --paths` ([added](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76376413/revisions) to OP)

Comment: In each folder listed under `data` there may be a folder called `labextensions`. Any of the `labextensions` folder which contains extensions or folders with extensions (e.g. `@jupyterlab/git` could be in `/Users/Rax/Library/Jupyter/labextensions/@jupyterlab/git`) - you can try (re)moving these folders (which is a descrutive action - backup first!) to see if this is the culprit

Comment: @krassowski Deleting a `labextensions` folder results in no extensions, but adding them back following the install instructions for each puts be back in the same place.

Comment: @krassowski No I've got [no extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76790341/656912)