# No Jupyter extensions installed

Tags: jupyter-lab, jupyter-extensions

I've installed several Jupyter Lab extensions following the instructions for each, but when I `jupyter labextension list`, I see nothing, and when I `jupyter server extension list` I get:

```
Config dir: /Users/Rax/.jupyter

Config dir: /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/etc/jupyter

Config dir: /usr/local/etc/jupyter
    jupyter_server_fileid enabled
    - Validating jupyter_server_fileid...
       X The module 'jupyter_server_fileid' could not be found (No module named 'jupyter_server_fileid'). Are you sure the extension is installed?
    jupyter_server_mathjax enabled
    - Validating jupyter_server_mathjax...
Package jupyter_server_mathjax took 0.0010s to import
      jupyter_server_mathjax  OK
    jupyter_server_terminals enabled
    - Validating jupyter_server_terminals...
Package jupyter_server_terminals took 0.0042s to import
      jupyter_server_terminals 0.4.4 OK
    jupyter_server_ydoc enabled
    - Validating jupyter_server_ydoc...
       X The module 'jupyter_server_ydoc' could not be found (No module named 'jupyter_server_ydoc'). Are you sure the extension is installed?
    jupyterlab enabled
    - Validating jupyterlab...
Package jupyterlab took 0.0234s to import
      jupyterlab 4.0.3 OK
    jupyterlab_git enabled
    - Validating jupyterlab_git...
Package jupyterlab_git took 0.0246s to import
      jupyterlab_git 0.41.0 OK
    nbclassic enabled
    - Validating nbclassic...
       X The module 'nbclassic' could not be found (No module named 'nbclassic'). Are you sure the extension is installed?
    nbdime enabled
    - Validating nbdime...
Package nbdime took 0.0000s to import
      nbdime 3.2.1 OK
    notebook_shim enabled
    - Validating notebook_shim...
Package notebook_shim took 0.0000s to import
A `_jupyter_server_extension_points` function was not found in notebook_shim. Instead, a `_jupyter_server_extension_paths` function was found and will be used for now. This function name will be deprecated in future releases of Jupyter Server.
      notebook_shim  OK
```

For `jupyter --paths` I get:

```
config:
    /Users/Rax/.jupyter
    /Users/Rax/Library/Python/3.11/etc/jupyter
    /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/etc/jupyter
    /usr/local/etc/jupyter
    /etc/jupyter
data:
    /Users/Rax/Library/Jupyter
    /Users/Rax/Library/Python/3.11/share/jupyter
    /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/share/jupyter
    /usr/local/share/jupyter
    /usr/share/jupyter
runtime:
    /Users/Rax/Library/Jupyter/runtime
```

How do I get the extensions I've installed to appear in Jupyter Lab?