# How do I remove pygments from Jupyter Lab?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

Even with an entirely pristine Jupyter Lab / Notebook (`pip install notebook`) installation in an otherwise clean virtual environment, I get an incomparable `pygments` extension flagged as installed but out of date. How do I prevent this?

```
jupyterlab_pygments v0.2.2 enabled  X (python, jupyterlab_pygments)
```

Comment: I think [this discussion here in the JupyterLab repo](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/14965#issuecomment-1694534597) addresses this. I don't yet see a specific solution proposed as they were still trying to sort it. There [seemed to be an environment issue where the two routes were installing to different places](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/14965#issuecomment-1701581193). Is yours different?

Comment: @Wayne Excellent, that may help also with some weirdness I'm getting with seeing other extensions that I haven't installed (at least not where they're showing up) and some [missing from where I _have_ installed them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76790341/656912).

Comment: @Wayne So it seems like [at least in the case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77105437/656912) of `jupyterlab_pygments` the package  is installed as a dependency for some other package, and once (pip) installed it gets automatically (jupyter) installed as an extension. I seem to be able to use the extensions manager to get rid of the extension though. Does that sound right?

Comment: Maybe. More importantly, does it help you stop getting that out of date notice? I'm guessing the answer is 'no' since I see [this here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77105437/8508004).

Comment: @Wayne For `jupyterlab_pygments` it works, but not in [that case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77105437/656912). That's a completely different scenario: those packages don't even show up in the extensions manager, and the corresponding packages python are installed nowhere on my machine. I've no idea why they're even being looked for.

Comment: Good! I'm glad to hear you at least made some progress on `jupyterlab_pygments`.

Comment: jupyterlab_pygments in relation to extension comes up again [here in a discussion at the Jupyter Discourse Forum](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/jupyter-reports-extension-errors-for-mystery-extensions/21435?u=fomightez) and so those curious may wish to see there, too.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab_pygments/issues/26) issue and requires no action. The extension is installed automatically when the corresponding package is installed, and the package is installed as a dependency for many others, so it's best to leave it alone.

Comment: Note that contrary to expectations, the 'uninstall' option in the Jupyter extensions manager does not just uninstall the extension, it now uninstalled the corresponding package, so that's not an option.