# Why is Jupyter looking for extensions I haven't installed?

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-extensions

Even in a completely pristine virtual environment I get errors of the following form

```
Package jupyter_server_terminals took 0.0020s to import
[W 2023-09-14 09:17:01.917 ServerApp] NAME | error adding extension (enabled: True): The module 'NAME' could not be found (No module named 'NAME'). Are you sure the extension is installed?
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/Rax/Documents/Projects/Coding/Python/venvs/automata/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jupyter_server/extension/manager.py", line 319, in add_extension
        extpkg = ExtensionPackage(name=extension_name, enabled=enabled)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/Users/Rax/Documents/Projects/Coding/Python/venvs/automata/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jupyter_server/extension/manager.py", line 183, in __init__
        self._load_metadata()
      File "/Users/Rax/Documents/Projects/Coding/Python/venvs/automata/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jupyter_server/extension/manager.py", line 198, in _load_metadata
        raise ExtensionModuleNotFound(msg) from None
    jupyter_server.extension.utils.ExtensionModuleNotFound: The module ’NAME' could not be found (No module named ’NAME'). Are you sure the extension is installed?
```

for

- `jupyter_server_fileid`
- `jupyter_server_mathjax`
- `jupyter_server_ydoc`
- `jupyterlab_git`
- `nbclassic`
- `nbdime`

My requirements include none of these packages, and none are installed, all I have is

```
notebook >=7.0
```

Why is Jupyter looking for these extensions in the first place? How do I prevent these warnings?

Comment: Cross-posted [here at the Jupyter Discourse Forum](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/jupyter-reports-extension-errors-for-mystery-extensions/21435?u=fomightez). Anyone interested should see an in depth discussion there.

Answer (score 1):

[Using](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/jupyter-reports-extension-errors-for-mystery-extensions/21435/2?u=orome)

```
jupyter server extension list --debug
```

will show what configuration files are responsible for installing extensions and deleting any of these that are responsible for extensions you do not want will likely address the issue.

Comment: In my case deleting the directory `/usr/local/etc/jupyter/jupyter_server_config.d/` got rid of all of these.