# About extension problem and note book 7 break

Tags: jupyter-notebook, extension-methods, auto-update

My extension is breaking Because when I setup my environment then the extension was not writing done,after that there is Jupyter Notebook 7 is not updating saying that that extension might broken so tell me How to solve this problem.

I tried to update the notebook 7 but it is not updating It is saying that the extension has been broken

Comment: Someone posted about this very recently, I think. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77054340/8508004) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77105437/why-is-jupyter-looking-for-extensions-i-havent-installed). I think what you are describing is related to [what is presently being discussed here at the Jupyter Discourse Forum](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/jupyter-reports-extension-errors-for-mystery-extensions/21435?u=fomightez) in relation to all that.

Comment: A brief summary of what worked is [now posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77113928/8508004).

Comment: ok let me see -